# Saving data from workspace to a specific path

Tags: matlab

I work with a dataset and want to save a variable from workspace to a directory in the form of, for example ***Label_1*** , ***Label_2*** , ... but unfortunately face with error.

```
for indImg = 1:100
.
.
.
  Label= ...     % this is a matrix
  savepath = './Data/50';
  save([savepath 'Label' '_' indImg],'Label');
end
```

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is shown because `indImg` is a double, and it expects a char.
You can convert it to a char with [num2str](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html).

You can use:

```
savepath = './Data/50';

for indImg = 1:100
.
.
.
  save(fullfile(savepath,['Label' '_' num2str(indImg)]),'Label');
end
```

Note that I moved the variable `savepath` outside the loop. You should do the same for any other variables which effectively do not change between loop iterations.